# sql join data from two tables

Tags: mysql

I wonder if someone help me to join data from two tables...spending all the day didn't manage...

**Code 1 selects:** 
Year | Turnover1 | Quantity1 | EurPerOrder1

```
SELECT Year(table1.ContractDate) AS Year,
  Sum(table1.TPrice) AS Turnover1,
  Count(table1.id) AS Quantity1,
  ROUND(Sum(table1.TPrice) / Count(table1.id), 0) AS EurPerOrder1
FROM table1
GROUP BY Year(table1.ContractDate) * 100
ORDER BY table1.ContractDate DESC
```

**Code2 selects:** 
Year | Turnover2 | Quantiry2 | EurPerOrder2

```
SELECT Year(table2.date) AS Year,
  Sum(table2.price) AS Turnover2,
  Count(table2.rid) AS Quantiry2,
  ROUND(Sum(table2.price) / Count(table2.rid), 0) AS EurPerOrder2
FROM table2
GROUP BY Year(table2.date) * 100
ORDER BY table2.date DESC
```

**And I need to join data like:**

Year | Turnover1 | Quantity1 | EurPerOrder1 | Turnover2 | Quantiry2 | EurPerOrder2

I need to have all data from both tables grouped by years. Even table2 doesnt have year 2013 anyway I would like it showed 0 or empty...
I have tried different ways using examples but nothing worked so I think the problem can occur because second table doesn't have all the years which are on table1...

Comment: Which is your DBMS? Also you need only matching by `YEAR` rows or also need all rows from `table1`?

Comment: Just update question so we know if you will use left or inner join. Good explanation can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)

Comment: What is `EurPerOrder3`?

Comment: I use mysql database. EurPerOrder3 was my mistake, I have already corrected... Thanx!

Comment: I see that you did not approve your anwers. Please if the question solves your problem approve answer.

Answer (score 0):

First: you can read pretty good explanation about the `JOINS` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)

Ok, according the question you need `LEFT JOIN`. This means all data from `table1` and only matching data from `table2`.

The `SELECT` must look like:

```
SELECT Year(table1.ContractDate) AS Year,
  Sum(table1.TPrice) AS Turnover1,
  Count(table1.id) AS Quantiry1,
  ROUND(Sum(table1.TPrice) / Count(table1.id), 0) AS EurPerOrder1, 
    Sum(table2.price) AS Turnover2,
    Count(table2.rid) AS Quantiry2, 
  ROUND(Sum(table2.price) / Count(table2.rid), 0) AS EurPerOrder2 
FROM 
    table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON Year(table1.ContractDate) = Year(table2.date)
GROUP BY 
    Year(table1.ContractDate) * 100, Year(table2.date) * 100
ORDER BY 
    table1.ContractDate DESC, table2.date DESC
```

Of course you need to process `NULL` values. See [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Please check SQL and correct it if there are erreors. I don't have live data to check (by running it).

Comment: Thank you very much! I am not sure if I need lift join but I would need to have all data from both tables grouped by years. Even table2 doesnt have year 2013 anyway I would like it showed 0 or empty...

Comment: Ok, @tester, if the answer solves your problem, please don't forget to approve it. And when you have reputation you can vote up. Also you have to study about `JOINs` this is a fundamental topic in `SQL`.